# Sending message to a SQS queue fails from local in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, connectionexception

I'm not able to send message to *sqs-queue* from my java application.
I am running **roribio16/alpine-sqs** docker image for SQS in my local and I've created a standard queue.

Code snippets:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableSqs
public class SQSConfig {

    private final String amazonAWSAccessKey;
    private final String amazonAWSSecretKey;
    private final String amazonSQSRegion;

    public SQSConfig(@Value("${aws.accesskey}") String amazonAWSAccessKey,
                     @Value("${aws.secretkey}") String amazonAWSSecretKey,
                     @Value("${sqs.aws.region}") String amazonSQSRegion) {
        this.amazonAWSAccessKey = amazonAWSAccessKey;
        this.amazonAWSSecretKey = amazonAWSSecretKey;
        this.amazonSQSRegion = amazonSQSRegion;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate() {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSClient());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSClient() {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(amazonSQSRegion)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()))
                .build();
    }

    private AWSStaticCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey));
    }

}
```

MessageProducerService:

```
@Component
public class SQSMessageProducerService {

    @Value("${sqs.endpoint}")
    private String amazonSQSEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String messageBody) {
        Message messageBuilt = MessageBuilder.withPayload(messageBody).build();
        try {
            queueMessagingTemplate.send(amazonSQSEndpoint, messageBuilt);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("message sent: " + messageBody);

    }
}
```

Calling using -

```
sqsMessageProducerService.sendMessage(userEvent.toString());
```

Error stack -

> InvalidAction; see the SQS docs. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code:
> 400; Error Code: InvalidAction; Request ID:
> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)

Vars from properties file -

```
sqs.endpoint=${SQS_ENDPOINT:http://localhost:9324/test-sns-queue}
sqs.aws.region=${SQS_AWS_REGION:us-west-2}
```

Also, SQS instance is up in my local and can be accessed using http://localhost:9325/.
Is there some config that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that the endpoint is `http://localhost:9324/queue/test-sns-queue`